# /dev/sda2 is full, anything suspicious here?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, opensuse

I ran out of room on a 20G partition I use for my OpenSuse linux OS.

I ran du -sh * to see where the big hard drive pits swells reside, and this is what I see:

```
4.7M    bin
47M     boot
48K     dev
24M     etc
164M    lib
17M     lib64
16K     lost+found
4.0K    mnt
4.0K    opt
du: cannot access ‘proc/7847/task/7847/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/7847/task/7847/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/7847/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/7847/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0       proc
964K    root
296M    run
7.2M    sbin
4.0K    selinux
32K     srv
0       sys
392K    tmp
3.8G    usr
2.4G    var
```

I don't see anything out of the ordinary... Is 3.8G too large for /usr?

This is what it looks like in /usr:

```
16K     X11R6
309M    bin
4.0K    games
20M     include
281M    lib
1.6G    lib64
80K     local
45M     sbin
1.6G    share
236K    src
0       tmp
16K     x86_64-suse-linux
```

Is anything unusual here? What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

here's my /var dir:

```
4.0K    X11R6
148M    adm
31M     cache
4.0K    crash
8.0K    games
du: cannot access ‘lib/named/proc/8443/task/8443/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘lib/named/proc/8443/task/8443/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘lib/named/proc/8443/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘lib/named/proc/8443/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
239M    lib
0       lock
32M     log
0       mail
4.0K    opt
297M    run
232K    spool
92K     tmp
12K     yp
```

Comment: `/var` having 2.4g looks strange, i would check there first.

Comment: i added `/var` -- anything look bad?

Comment: `$> sudo du -sh /var`

Comment: These numbers don’t add up. Where’s `/home`? Did you run `du` as root?

Comment: i omitted /home and /media because those are mounted drives in my setup. i did run as root.. that's odd that they didn't add up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not unusual. My `/usr` directory is actually 10G. You have to remember this directory contains a lot of stuff related to the programs you have installed. Most "user installed" (hence the name of the directory) programs will end up being in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib` depending on whether it's a program or a library. So, the more software you have installed, the bigger you can expect this directory to be. Files associated with the program also often end up in the directory, especially icons in `/usr/share/icons`.

Your `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/share` directories alone take up 3.2G of the 3.8G that `/usr` is taking up. I would venture to say you have a number of 64 bit libraries installed. Perhaps you could try [removing any orphaned packages from your system](http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/zypper-cookbook-autoremove-packages-and-remove-orphaned-packages/).

It's been a while since I've used OpenSUSE, but it looks like you can list orphaned packages with this command

```
 zypper packages --orphaned
```

Some [threads on the OpenSUSE forums](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/400628-Zypper-clean) suggest this will also lower your `/var` disk usage.

```
zypper clean
```

Comment: wow i dont know if that alone was it, or the fact that i rebooted.. but now I have 15G available... could it have been the reboot?

Comment: A reboot might have done two things:
1) Cleared /tmp (but that was only 392K in your case).
2) It would have closed any open but already deleted files. Those files would not show up on `du` but would continue to use diskspace until their handle was closed.

Comment: Rebooting would normally only affect `/tmp` and `/var`. Hard to say where the 15G came from without having seen the output of the `du -sh` command run as root.